# How do I exclude folders from a fortify sca jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins, fortify, static-code-analysis

In my jenkinsbuild I have a Maven(v3.1.0) project with a Fortify SCA plugin. I'm searching for the command to exclude a folder from the sca test and the place this command belongs. The Java project to test will be loaded from a GIT repository.

My commands(working):

(Build)

```
clean -Dfortify.sca.buildId=${JOB_NAME} sca:clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install -Dfortify.sca.buildId=${JOB_NAME} sca:translate
```

(Post-Build)

```
-Dfortify.sca.Xmx=4G
-Dfortify.sca.Xms=2G
-Dfortify.sca.Xss=100M
-Dfortify.sca.PermGen=1G
-Dfortify.sca.64bit=true
-Dfortify.sca.verbose=true
-Dfortify.sca.debug=false
-Dfortify.sca.buildId=${JOB_NAME}
-Dfortify.sca.toplevel.artifactId=test
-Dfortify.sca.scan.failOnError=true
-Dfortify.sca.upload=false
-Dfortify.sca.upload.failOnError=true
-Dfortify.f360.url=${SSC_URL}
-Dfortify.f360.authToken=${SSC_AUTH_TOKEN}
-Dfortify.f360.projectName=${JOB_NAME}
-Dfortify.f360.projectVersion=current
sca:scan
```

Comment: As far as i know you need to configure this in Fortify itself. The fortify plugin does not offer such things. Furthermore i would recommend to update to at least to Maven 3.1.1 or better to 3.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Fortify Maven plugin (4.21) has a property to exclude files/folders from scan:

```
-Dcom.fortify.sca.exclude="fileA;fileB;fileC"
```

Or you can define Fortify properties in a file and import it:

```
-Dfortify.sca.properties.file=fortify.properties
```